# Merge data from column of one table (source) into another table (target)

Tags: sql, merge

I am new to SQL and have been trying to populate a new table (target) with data points from an existing table (source). Both tables have a unique identifier for linkage.

The source table is called "medical_history" and includes information about whether each patient has (marked as a 1) or does not have (marked as a 0) asthma:

| patient_id | asthma_1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 |

The target table, "treatment", has an empty column called "asthma" which is empty at present. I need it to be populated with the data from source table called "medical_history" (the table is much bigger in reality, but this example is for one column for simplicity).

| patient_id | asthma |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 |

I have tried examples found online such as:

```
MERGE INTO treatment AS TARGET
USING medical_history AS SOURCE
ON patient_id
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE 
TARGET.asthma_1=SOURCE.asthma;
```

This doesn't run and I get an error message:

> An unexpected token "UPDATE TARGET.asthma_1=SOURCE" was found following "WHEN MATCHED THEN"

Can anyone suggest how to get this code to run?

Comment: Using all capitals is the internet equivalent of shouting, which is pretty rude if you want help. Please use normal case when writing titles (and the body of a question or answer). I have edited for your, but please keep this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the  `SET` keyword after the `WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE` clause opening. A complete `MERGE` statement can look like this:

```
MERGE
INTO public.treatment t
USING public.medical_history s
 ON s.patient_id = t.patient_id
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
  asthma     = s.asthma
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (
  patient_id
, asthma
) VALUES (
  s.patient_id
, s.asthma
);
```

Comment: This is fantastic! Thank you so much. I spent ages trying to work this out and you have fixed it. Really appreciate your time.